# ValueError at /api/loanextension/add/ Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: biju>>": "LoanExtension.owner" must be a "LoanApplication" instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class LoanApplication(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="loan_user", **optional)
profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='profile_user')
amount = models.DecimalField(_('Amount') ,max_digits=5, default=30000, decimal_places=0, help_text='Please fill the amount required')
period = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Days') ,default=30, help_text='Please fill the repayment time required')
timestamp = models.DateField(_('Date') , default=datetime.date.today, help_text='Date of Application')
status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, max_length=20, default='1')
is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)

class LoanExtension(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(LoanApplication)
new_tenure = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Days'), default=30, help_text='Please fill the repayment time required')
new_loan_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, default=30000, decimal_places=0, help_text='Please fill the amount required')
datestamp = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
interest = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, default=30000, decimal_places=0)
extension_fee = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, default=30000, decimal_places=0)
is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.owner)

class LoanExtensionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = LoanExtension

    fields = ['id',
              'new_tenure',
              'new_loan_amount',
              'interest',
              'extension_fee',
              'datestamp',
              'owner'
              ]
```

I want to assign the loan extension to loan application which is connected by a foreign key, when I am adding it throws the value error, please give me some help to solve it. 
Is this way of foreign key is a right way or should I provide user as foreign key, please suggest, Thank you.
I am sorry, I forgot to add views, it is as follows.

```
class LoanExtensionCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateAPIView):
queryset = LoanExtension.objects.all()
serializer_class = LoanExtensionSerializer
authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    owner =self.request.user
    serializer.save(owner=owner)
```

Comment: post code where you adding that foriegn key

Comment: You need to show the view where you are doing this.

Comment: itzmeontv, Roseman, I have changed the owner = self.request.user to owner = LoanApplication.objects.get(user=self.request.user) and it is working. Do I need to use the foreign key this way or keep user as foreign key, could you please suggest? Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the owner = self.request.user to 
owner = LoanApplication.objects.get(user=self.request.user) and it is working.